# EntityFramework inheritance using existent base class instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I am using TPT strategy in my model.

Here's follow my Context:

```
public class MyTestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Persons");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Seller>().ToTable("Sellers");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And here my entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Seller : Person
{
    public decimal Comissao { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to reuse an already existent database register.
I have 2 CRUD's, one for Person, and another to Seller.

Scenario:

I have 10 persons in my database and 0 sellers, like this seed:

```
using (var ctx = new MyTestContext())
{
    Func<int, Person> selector = i => new Person
    {
        Name = string.Format("Person {0}", i)
    };
    var persons = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(selector);
    ctx.Persons.AddRange(persons);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want to add new Seller, but I want to reuse alredy existent Person in database:

```
using (var ctx = new MyTestContext())
{
    var seller = new Seller { Id = 1, Comissao = 10 };
    ctx.Sellers.Add(seller);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When Entity Framework save, he create a new Person, and a new Seller.

How can I use inheritance strategy and be able to use the Id that I assigned in Seller instead to create a new Person and use this new Id?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use TPT for **one to one-or-zero** relationship.

Because to be able to have **one to one-or-zero** relationship. You need to have `Seller` property on `Person` and `Person` property on `Seller`.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Seller Seller { get; set; }
}
public class Seller : Person
{
    public decimal Comissao { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

But above code doesn't work, because `Seller` property on Person will also be inherited to `Seller` and it will be considered as another relationship.

## Solution

- Have another abstract class called `BasePerson`
- Both `Person` and `Seller` are derived from `BasePerson`
- Use Table Per Concrete Class mapping

Here are the classes

```
public abstract class BasePerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person : BasePerson
{
    public Seller Seller { get; set; }
}
public class Seller : BasePerson
{
    public decimal Comissao { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}    
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configures one to one-or-zero relationship.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Seller>().HasRequired(x => x.Person).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Seller);
    }
}
```

## Sample Usage

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    context.People.Add(new Person { Id = 1 });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    context.Sellers.Add(new Seller { Id = 1 });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    // Throws DBUpdateException, Person Id = 2 doesn't exist.
    context.Sellers.Add(new Seller { Id = 2 });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```